# How to pass ArrayList to Local Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite

I have my database created and parsed my xml to an arraylist to show in a listview. I am trying to save that arraylist to the database but the problem is I needed to tie the database to my Model and now it wants me to pass it the model when I need to pass it the ArrayList. I tried to change the addEmployee() method in the database to accept an ArrayList but then I am not able to get the getters from the model class to set the data.

I have been trying for a couple days and I am just completly stuck on how to get my parsed data to save into a SQLite database.

```
//Add new employee
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, employee.getEmployee_number());
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, employee.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, employee.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, employee.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, employee.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, employee.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, employee.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, employee.getCost_center_id());

        //Inserting Row
        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);
        database.close();
        return true;
    }

public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                final XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
                mEmployees.clear();
                mEmployees.addAll(employees);

                DatabaseHandler databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                db = databasehandler.getWritableDatabase();
                databasehandler.onCreate(db);
                databasehandler.addEmployee(employees);
                ArrayList<Employee> mTopList = databasehandler.getAllEmployees(); //this is empty

                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mTopListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mBottomListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mMangerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to change the addEmployee() method in the database to accept an ArrayList but then I am not able to get the getters from the model class to set the data.

Don't you just need a loop?

```
final DatabaseHandler databasehandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
final ArrayList<Employee> employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
for (Employee e : employees) {
    databasehandler.addEmployee(e);
}
```

---

If you really want to make a method with a list, same idea...

```
public boolean addEmployees(List<Employee> employees) { 
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    for (Employee e : employees) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, e.getEmployee_number());
        ...

        database.insert(TABLE_EMPLOYEE, null, values);       
    }
    database.close();
    return true;
}
```

---

**Tip** Use a CursorAdapter if you want to show a SQLite database in a ListView, then you won't be shuffling an ArrayList in memory.

Comment: Is there a way to see what is actually in the database after the loop?

Comment: from the app? Use a List view adapter. Otherwise,  download the database off the device or use a tool like Stetho while you develop

Comment: Just trying to see if it's actually saving the data to the database to be able to pull a record out of it that is tied to a specific number attribute.

Comment: Makes sense. Give Stetho a try

Comment: Stetho looks nice, just one question if you know something about it. Since I already have a network call, do I just add their interceptor to mine or wrap theirs around my network call?

Comment: Never mind, found on docs that I can just add it to the onCreate method to make their InitializerBuilder

Comment: OK, you are a life saver, but do have 1 last question, so I can see the database with Stetho, but for some reason the first 9 rows are empty and then start at row 10. Could that be the UI of Stetho or is that normal for android? I am very new to making and using databases in general.

Comment: If you just want the database functionality, you don't need the network interceptor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133813/discussion-between-adam-gardner-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Umm, well I doubt it's UI related. For example, `employee.getFirst_name()` is empty, then your database is empty. There's other libraries for databases that you could look into like SugarOrm, ActiveAndriod, or Realm database

Comment: Are any of these able to handle parsed xml?

Comment: Jackson or XStream can deserialize XML into Java objects, but I don't think a relational database in Android that supports XML documents is a good "separation of principles"

Comment: I'm just parsing an XML web service and displaying it into list, I figured SQLite be the best as I need to learn to remove duplicates and to take just 1 row from it to populate another listview in same activity

Comment: You can remove duplicates using a `Set` *before* you insert

Comment: Im getting the SQLite_COnSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY as I am trying to populate the database with 2 rows that have the same employee number. The service is passing it back twice, don't ask why. But I am having an issue deleting a duplicate.

Comment: I'd fix the service :) But, yeah, not really sure about the SQL issue. I'd recommend asking a new post about it